# Jolt spec to parse and transform JSON array

Tags: json, jolt

This is my first time using Jolt and I am amazed at transformations it can perform. I followed the documentation and few posts online.

However, I am still have challenges with:

- concatenating new values to existing values (url in this case)
- moving concatenated value to right place
- adding a default key-value pair if it doesn't exist in input JSON
- Assigning JSON object to correct JSON array.

I have the following input

```json
{
  "Body": [
    {
      "username": "some-user"
    },
    {
      "password": "*******"
    }
  ],
  "hostSource": "infos",
  "Host": [
    {
      "HOST_NAME": "xyz.com"
    },
    {
      "PORT": "9085"
    }
  ],
  "Headers": [
    {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  ]
}
```

and my expected output is:

```json
{
  "templateConfig": {
    "commonClientConfig ": {
      "item": [
        {
          "name": "Main API - BASICAUTH",
          "request": {
            "auth": {
              "type": "basic",
              "basic": [
                {
                  "key": "password",
                  "value": "*******",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "key": "username",
                  "value": "some-user",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              ]
            },
            "method": "GET",
            "header": [
              {
                "key": "Content-Type",
                "value": "application/json",
                "type": "text"
              }
            ],
            "url": {
              "raw": "xyz.com/v9085/some-default-value"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

After referring few posts and documentation, I was able to get this far with the spec:

```json
 [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Body": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "commonClientConfig.item.request.auth.basic[&2].key",
            "@(1,&)": "commonClientConfig.item.request.auth.basic[&2].value"
          }
        }
      },
      "Headers": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "commonClientConfig.item.request.header[&2].key",
            "@(1,&)": "commonClientConfig.item.request.header[&2].value"
          }
        }
      },
      "Host": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@(1,&)": "commonClientConfig.item.request.url.raw"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "content": "=join('/', @(2,commonClientConfig.item.request.url.raw))"
    }
  }    
]
```

I would really appreciate if someone can provide some guidance here with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following consecutive specs

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "#Main API - BASICAUTH": "name",
      "Body": {
        "#basic": "request.auth.type",
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "request.auth.basic[&2].key",
            "@": "request.auth.basic[&2].value",
            "#string": "request.auth.basic[&2].type"
          }
        }
      },
      "Headers": {
        "#GET": "request.method",
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "request.header[&2].key",
            "@": "request.header[&2].value",
            "#text": "request.header[&2].type"
          }
        }
      },
      "Host": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "request.url"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "request": {
        "url": "=join('/', @(2,request.url))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "request": {
        "url": "=concat(@(1,url), /some-default-value)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "request": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "url": "&1.&.raw"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "templateConfig.commonClientConfig.item[]"
    }
  }
]
```

where

- `join` function is used to derive concatenated string from combining
  each elements of the array without repeatedly mentioning them, while
  `concat` is used just to handle the single concatenation of the
  default string.
- Notice that the innermost common key is `request` for the arrays `Body`, `Headers` and `Host` those should be individually treated depending on the need for each, and they are finally accumulated under common nodes(`templateConfig.commonClientConfig.item[]`) within the last shift spec.

Comment: can u pls explain the url creation and movement within hierarchy, especially the last but one shift operation? Also, per original question, the url value needs a join with additional value that's not present in the input json, how to concatenate that?

Comment: Hi @Barbaros - Thanks. Is there any tip/trick to use these tokens? for ex. If i have to comprehend, what this spec does -> "*": "&1.&", "url": "&1.&.raw"? The results are not obvious unless you are using the correct spec. On other hand, I was exploring mapneat library that uses Kotlin and it prints debug statements that tells what value is available for the variables.

Comment: @Dwarrior Jolt is just a library developed under github, and as far as I know there's no such IDE or framework for it, but you can use [the site](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com) , which I use too, as a playground by trial and catch method to develop the comprehension. I like the way doing it :) Btw, check out my recent answers if you have time.

Comment: sure thank u again for getting me so far, I will work on some more transformations to get a better feel of this library. Will open up new post in case I am unable to achieve something. I really like the power of this library but the examples are not that thorough in the documentation.

Comment: I tried one more example and have posted question on that here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69211561. I would really appreciate if you can provide any feedback on the way I am approaching this problem using JOLT.